# Error type 3 Error: Activity class {org.godot.k/com.godot.game.GodotApp} does not exist

Tags: android, export, godot

I am trying to export an app to Android device (from Godot Engine), but terminal gives me an error message:

```
adb: failed to install C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp/Godot/tmpexport.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED: Install canceled by user]
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=org.godot.k/com.godot.game.GodotApp }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {org.godot.k/com.godot.game.GodotApp} does not exist.
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think you canceled the exporting process.
You should try deleting this .apk file C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp/Godot/tmpexport.apk

Comment: The problem is the "tmpexport.apk" file isn't in my computer...

Comment: And the error is a little bit different now: `adb: failed to install C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp/Godot/tmpexport.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Failed to collect certificates from /data/app/vmdl1535253827.tmp/base.apk: Attempt to get length of null array]
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=org.godot.k/com.godot.game.GodotApp }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {org.godot.k/com.godot.game.GodotApp} does not exist.`

Comment: Maybe this could help [link](https://godotengine.org/qa/25714/android-export-debug-error-activity-class-godotengine-godot)

Comment: Thank you, but I think my package name isnt wrong - com.godot.game